# Custom filter for ng-options list

Tags: angularjs-filter

I created a multiselect dropdown which is populated on the basis of an input element, any text can be entered into it and that text becomes the label of dropdown with some special text, these special text can be any of the planets name. Now I want to create a custom filter on this ng-option list so that only all the planets are sorted in the order of their planetary position inside the dropdown, other text may go above or below the planets.
Any Idea how to implement such a custom filter. I tried some of the options but when I return the list from filter I get infamous angualr error :"Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!"

Comment: Do you have any code you can share with us to check out?

Comment: Thanks niro for your reply...

Comment: Thanks @niro for your reply .... I have created a plunker to show what I am trying to do. In order to see the error pipe the filter inside the directive template.... http://plnkr.co/edit/w99TnKj9UEoGoYZ5KbWu?p=preview